# Fetching array from a resource

Tags: php, mysql

This is a sample of the code in one of my php pages:

```
$query_result=mysql_query($query);
$_SESSION['result']=$query_result;
```

And this is a sample of the code in the other page in the same project:

```
session_start();    
$row=mysql_fetch_array($_SESSION['result']);
```

This gives me an error that says " mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given "... can anyone help me figure this out ... thanks :-)

Comment: The content of $_SESSION['result'] is not what gets returned by the preceding mysql_query call.  Also (I'm fairly sure) you can't store resources in the session anyway. (EDIT: I see you fixed the first problem.  but I'm fairly sure the second one still holds)

Comment: the query result can't just be passed around between pages!

Comment: you could try get_resource_type to see if it's resource at all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query resources don't persist across sessions.

> It is currently impossible to register resource variables in a
>   session. For example, you cannot create a connection to a database and
>   store the connection id as a session variable and expect the
>   connection to still be valid the next time the session is restored.
>   PHP functions that return a resource are identified by having a return
>   type of resource in their function definition.

from [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php#refsect1-function.session-register-notes)

Comment: you can always pass the query string in session and run this on the proper page

Answer (score 0):

this error comes due to not found the object pass in mysql_fetch_array();

You should do like that:

```
$query_result=mysql_query($query);
$_SESSION['result']=$query_result;
```

and

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($_SESSION['result']);
```